# Redshift Serializable isolation violation error

Tags: concurrency, redshift, snapshot-isolation

Our setup: We have a Redshift cluster as our data warehouse. We have a Postgres OLTP DB from which a number of write-heavy tables are getting replicated into Redshift using DMS. We use dbt to then build BI models from these tables loaded from Postgres on an hourly basis. These models take up to 9 minutes to build on average.

We have started to experience "Serializable isolation violation error" in Redshift when the dbt models are getting created. By querying the system tables, I was able to find the queries executed in these conflicting transactions and it looks like DMS writes are happening on the tables that are read by the dbt model query. My conclusion is that this is the reason for the Redshift error since our database is set to SERIALIZABLE isolation.

I am thinking the possible solutions are:

1. Modify ETL process to load data in batches from Postgres rather than doing CDC replication: This allows me to time the dbt model creating jobs to run after the ETL sync job has completed.
2. Change Redshift DB isolation level to SNAPSHOT: Since I don't care about the dbt models to be consistent with concurrent DML operation results, I am guessing its safe to lower the isolation level to SNAPSHOT.

I am leaning towards the second option since its simpler and it makes sense to me. But I want to get feedback on this.

Thank you!